# disclosure button mapview

Tags: button, mkmapview, disclosure

I'll see if I can explain the problem and if I can lend a hand.

I have a "VC source" with multiple buttons, and through a switch (case) to select each of them, dynamically loads me another "VCdest", with images, texts, different depending on selection.

On the other hand, I have a map with annotations, each one with its disclosure button.
The problem is that when you select the disclosure button of the annotation take me to the VCdest, but loaded dynamically depending on the annotation,it is as if he called to a case determined the switch.

Any ideas of how you can make this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your annotation class needs to be able to contain the information you need to make a decision about the VCDest. Add a property to your class and set up each annotation in the way you are doing so at the moment. Then when the disclosure button is called you'll be given the annotation that created that callout and you can get the value of that property and run through a switch statement.

Comment: Finally choose to enter all the code again switch on the part of the disclosure button, thank you so much, Craig